# How to handle token expiry in azure msal react?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

I'm using Azure Single Sign-On (SSO) for login in my React application, and I'm encountering issues with handling token expiry and renewal. After a successful login, I obtain a token and save it in the `localStorage`. However, when the token expires or is about to expire, I want to acquire a new token and update it in the `localStorage`.

I've created a hook that runs every 3 seconds to check if the token has expired or is about to expire. If it is, I call the acquireTokenSilent method to obtain a new token and update it in the local storage. This process repeats continuously.

Here's the relevant code I've implemented:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import jwt from 'jwt-decode';
import { backendScopeRequest } from '../config/authConfig';
import { useAuthStore } from '../store/auth';

const REFRESH_THRESHOLD = 300; // 5 minutes in seconds

export const useBackendTokenCheckExpirationTime = () => {
  const interval = useRef(null);
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
  const { updateBackendAccessToken, updateLoggedInUserProfile } = useAuthStore();

  const setRefreshTime = () => {
    const backendAccessToken = localStorage.getItem('backendAccessToken');
    if (backendAccessToken) {
      const decodeToken = jwt(backendAccessToken);
      const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Current time in seconds
      const timeUntilExpiry = decodeToken.exp - currentTime - REFRESH_THRESHOLD;
      localStorage.setItem('backendRefreshTime', timeUntilExpiry);
      return timeUntilExpiry;
    }
    return null;
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {};

  const acquireTokenWithRefreshToken = async () => {
    try {
      if (accounts.length && instance) {
        const response = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
          account: accounts[0],
          ...backendScopeRequest,
        });
        const decodeToken = jwt(response.accessToken);
        localStorage.setItem('backendAccessToken', response.accessToken);
        updateBackendAccessToken(response.accessToken);
        updateLoggedInUserProfile(decodeToken);
        const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        const timeUntilExpiry = decodeToken.exp - currentTime - REFRESH_THRESHOLD;
        localStorage.setItem('backendRefreshTime', timeUntilExpiry);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
      handleLogout();
      // Handle token refresh error
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      const backendRefreshTime = setRefreshTime();
      if (backendRefreshTime !== null && backendRefreshTime <= 0) {
        acquireTokenWithRefreshToken();
      }
    }, 3000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval.current);
  }, []);
};
```

The issue I'm facing is that the code above doesn't seem to refresh the token correctly. Even when the token has expired, it still uses the old token from `localStorage`, resulting in a 401 error from the API.

I'm relatively new to Azure SSO, and I'm looking for guidance on how to properly handle token expiry in Azure MSAL React. Specifically, how can I obtain a new token when the old one expires and update it in the `localStorage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `acquireTokenWithRefreshToken` function seems correct. It attempts to silently acquire a new token using the `acquireTokenSilent` method and then updates the token in local storage. However, you need to make sure this function is called when the token has expired.
Below are the changes i have did for hook

- I've increased the token check interval to 1 minute (`TOKEN_CHECK_INTERVAL`) to reduce the frequency of token checks.
- The `checkTokenExpiry` function now checks if the token is about to expire or has expired based on the `REFRESH_THRESHOLD`. If it is, it triggers token renewal.
- I've added a call to `checkTokenExpiry` immediately after mounting to check token expiry as soon as the component loads.

Here's an updated version of your `useBackendTokenCheckExpirationTime` `hook`:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from  'react';
import { useMsal } from  '@azure/msal-react';
import  jwt  from  'jwt-decode';
import { backendScopeRequest } from  '../src/authConfig';
import { useAuthStore } from  '../src/storeauth';

const  REFRESH_THRESHOLD  =  300; // 5 minutes in seconds
const  TOKEN_CHECK_INTERVAL  =  60000; // 1 minute in milliseconds


export  const  useBackendTokenCheckExpirationTime  = () => {
const  interval  =  useRef(null);
const { instance, accounts } =  useMsal();
const { updateBackendAccessToken, updateLoggedInUserProfile } =  useAuthStore();
const  acquireTokenWithRefreshToken  =  async () => { 
try {  
if (accounts.length  &&  instance) {
const  response  =  await  instance.acquireTokenSilent({
account:  accounts[0],
});
const  decodeToken  =  jwt(response.accessToken);
localStorage.setItem('backendAccessToken', response.accessToken); 
localStorage.getItem('backendAccessToken')
updateBackendAccessToken(response.accessToken);
updateLoggedInUserProfile(decodeToken);
console.log('Token refreshed');
console.log('Token renewed:', decodeToken);
}
} catch (error) {  
console.log('Error refreshing token', error);  // Handle token refresh error
}
};
useEffect(() => {
const  checkTokenExpiry  = () => {
const  backendAccessToken  =  localStorage.getItem('backendAccessToken');
if (backendAccessToken) {
const  decodeToken  =  jwt(backendAccessToken); 
const  currentTime  =  Math.floor(Date.now() /  1000); // Current time in seconds
const  timeUntilExpiry  =  decodeToken.exp  -  currentTime; 
if (timeUntilExpiry  <=  REFRESH_THRESHOLD) {     // Token is about to expire or has expired, refresh it
acquireTokenWithRefreshToken();
}
}
};
interval.current  =  setInterval(checkTokenExpiry, TOKEN_CHECK_INTERVAL);
checkTokenExpiry(); // Check token expiry immediately after mounting     
return () =>  clearInterval(interval.current);
}, []);
return  null; // You might not need to return anything from this hook

};
```

**Result**

[image]

[image]

**Here are the tokens generated in regular intervals:**
[image]
**Local Stoarge**
[image]

Comment: Yes. @SPT. Thanks SaiVamshiKrishna it really hepls and for your time in look into my question. Its much appreciated